# Join Using Maximum Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table that I am trying to join with based on an ID, however I only want to join with the rows that have the maximum "PeriodDT" (a datetime column) for that ID.

I have tried using the Top 1 order by that "PeriodDT" however it will only let me select one column or I get the error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Here is the query I Used:

```
Select  a.Name as PropertyName,
        a.PropertyNum as PropertyNum,
        a.City as City,
        a.State as State,
        b.Name as LoanName,
        b.LoanNum,
        (select Top 1 c.IntRate as IntRate,
        c.MaturityDT    
        from vNoteDetail c where c.LoanID = b.LoanID Order By c.PeriodDT DESC)
from vProperty a join vLoan b on a.LoanID = b.LoanId
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY clientid ORDER BY perioddt DESC) rn, 
                intrate, 
                perioddt                    MaturityDT, 
                loanid 
         FROM   vnotedetail) 
SELECT a.NAME        AS PropertyName, 
       a.propertynum AS PropertyNum, 
       a.city        AS City, 
       a.state       AS State, 
       b.NAME        AS LoanName, 
       b.loannum, 
       c.intrate, 
       c.maturitydt, 
FROM   vproperty a 
       JOIN vloan b 
         ON a.loanid = b.loanid 
       JOIN cte c 
         ON c.loanid = b.loanid 
WHERE  c.rn = 1
```

FYI restrictions of subquery [CHECK THIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189543(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select  a.Name as PropertyName,
    a.PropertyNum as PropertyNum,
    a.City as City,
    a.State as State,
    b.Name as LoanName,
    b.LoanNum,
    v1.IntRate,
    v1.MaturityDT    
from vProperty a join vLoan b on a.LoanID = b.LoanId
CROSS APPLY         (select Top 1 c.IntRate as IntRate,
    c.MaturityDT    
    from vNoteDetail c where c.LoanID = b.LoanID Order By c.PeriodDT DESC) AS V1
```